# How to use "NOT" operator on .htaccess redirection?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm using .htaccess to redirect users from multiple old domains to a new domain. Something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite3.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, I'd like to know if I could use the NOT operator to redirect any domain except newsite.com, like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond != %{HTTP_HOST} http://newsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Official manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

You have placed `!=` in wrong place PLUS `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains domain name only so no protocol should be there:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=newsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```